# How to check if a string is included in a int and to remove it?

Tags: python, string, integer

Hey I would like to know if there is a way I can make sure nobody type "1004gg0" into the game and crash it? It asks for a number and the number is an integer but I always get people either accidently or on purpose writing in strings into an integer place.

Comment: `try: int("1004gg0") except ValueError:...`

Comment: You can check if a string only has numbers with "s.isdigit()".

Answer (score 3):

Instead of checking before, let `int` check it for you. Just catch the conversion exception and reject the number:

```
def get_number_from_user(message):
    while True:
        user_input = raw_input(message)
        try:
            number = int(user_input)
            break
        except ValueError:
            # Keep asking
            pass
    return number
```

And you would use it as:

```
param = get_number_from_user("Insert number here: ")
print param
```

If you are using Python 3, then replace `raw_input` with `input`.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand how I would connect this or for it to work can I have an example?

Answer (score 1):

Convert the string to int, and let the user know if it fails:

```
try:
    number = int(s)
except ValueError:
    # This is not an int
```

Comment: `TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'type'`

Comment: I thought 'string' was the type's name. That's what I get for using C#, Java and Python all at once... I'll fix it.